# importerror: cant import name

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Board(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        GridLayout.__init__(self)
        self.cols=3
        self.list_all_buttons = []
        for i in range(9):
            self.b1= Button(text=" "+str(i))
            self.b1.index=I #new property of Button
            self.list_all_buttons.append(self.b1)
            self.add_widget(self.b1)
            self.b1.bind(on_press=self.click)
   

    def click(self, touch1): # touch1 returns button clicked
        if touch1.index %2==0:
            touch1.text += " Hello Even"
            touch1.background_color = (0, 250, 0, 1)
        else:
            touch1.text += " Hello Odd"
            touch1.background_color = (250, 0, 0, 1)  #diffrent color

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'based graphics'
        return Board()

TestApp().run()
```

this is my code i am trying to do a 9 buttons board but when i run it the program write this that it can import name app from kivy.app

```
"C:\Users\user1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/damka.py"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\user1\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-01-11_17.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\user1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\user1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\user1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\damka.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
 ImportError: cannot import name 'App' from 'kivy.app' (C:\Users\user1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

what to do? i am new in python so i need help for started! thanks for all helpers!

Comment: When I run your code (after installing `kivy`), I get a syntax error because you typed `self.b1.index=I` instead of `self.b1.index=i`. However, once I change that, it runs fine. Are you sure you installed `kivy` correctly? I can't think of anything else that would be causing this problem.

Comment: i think so but if not how do i unistall it? so i can install it all over again

Comment: Sometimes, for my device, I have to first call `import kivy` before everything else. Try adding it to the beginning of your code